# A puzzle about solving equations

Tags: equation-solving

> my wolfram version: 13.1

This is a very simple equation, and I want to solve for "A".

$$
\frac{A^2 \pi^{3 / 2}}{2 \sqrt{2} a^{3 / 2}}=1
$$

And I'm sure "A" is positive, so his solution is

$$
A=\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{3 / 4} a^{3 / 4}
$$

As you can see when I solve this equation directly, I can't solve it

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
$Assumptions = a > 0

Solve[(A^2*Pi^(3/2))/(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2)) == 1, A]
```

[image]

To solve this problem, I replaced "A^2" with "A", and then I took the square root of "A" and got the answer

[image]

I'm confused about this

Comment: With v13.1 on a Mac I get `{{A -> (2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2))/Pi^(3/2)}}`. If the domain is specified as `Reals` then `{{A -> ConditionalExpression[ (2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2))/Pi^(3/2), a > 0]}}`

Comment: Did you mean to have `A` or `A^2` in your first code snippet?  It's `A^2` in the screenshot but `A` in the code.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert In the first equation, I used "A^2", I tried to find A, got A positive number, failed, so I replaced "A^2" with "a", and took the square root

Comment: Please add the code text for all of the code sample to your question. Currently the question looks confusing (at first glance, at least). And user64494 is clearly fooled.

Comment: 以防你没听懂，我现在用汉语重复一遍：你贴错代码了。

Comment: @xzczd I have do it

Comment: Omit `$Assumptions = a > 0`, and the desired solution results.

Comment: I am posting this comment in two forms: English and "Google "translated mainland Chinese. It has been very unclear whether the "A" version or the "A^2"version is the actual problem with which you desired assistance. To receive answer in form that you seem to want, you have tell Mathematica what you desire: ToRadicals[Solve[(A*Pi^(3/2))/(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2)) == 1 && 
    A >= 0, A, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]] which produces in Mathematica 13.2.1 the that answer: {{A -> ConditionalExpression[(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2))/Pi^(3/2), 
     a > 0]}}.

Comment: @我心永恒 我以两种形式发布此评论：英文和“Google”翻译的大陆中文。 目前还不清楚“A”版本或“A^2”版本是否是您需要帮助的实际问题。 要以您似乎想要的形式接收答案，您已经告诉 Mathematica 您想要什么： ToRadicals[Solve[(A*Pi^(3/2))/(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2) ) == 1 &&
     A >= 0, A, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]] 在{{A -> ConditionalExpression[(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2))/Pi^(3/2), 
     a > 0]}}。

Comment: @我心永恒 I suggest reading [how to enter usable code from notebook](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [common pitfalls and misunderstanding of Wolfram Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users). Also, remember that Mathematica generally works in complex mode. The documentation almost always when reals are assumed.

Comment: @我心永恒  我建议阅读[如何从笔记本输入可用代码](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on -this-site) 和 [Wolfram Mathematica 的常见陷阱和误解](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)。 另外，请记住 Mathematica 通常在复数模式下工作。 假设实数时，文档几乎总是如此。

Answer (score 3):

This behavior seems to exist for version 12.2 and later.  You don't mention any assumptions you are making, but this is what I get with different assumptions in version 13.2.1.

```
$Assumptions = a > 0

Solve[(A^2*Pi^(3/2))/(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2)) == 1, A]
```

The result matches your result, but with

```
$Assumptions =.

Solve[(A^2*Pi^(3/2))/(2*Sqrt[2]*a^(3/2)) == 1, A]
(*{{A -> (2/Pi)^(3/4)*(-a^(3/4))}, {A -> (2/Pi)^(3/4)*a^(3/4)}}*)
```

The result is what you would expect.  Prior to version 12.2, the result is what you would expect in both cases.  This new behavior has broken a lot of my calculations.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates correctly without assumptions!

Comment: @UlrichNeuman I know.  That's what `$Assumptions=.` assures after I made the first assumption `a>0`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding domain `Reals`,

```
Solve[(A \[Pi]^(3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)) == 1, A, Reals]
```

> `{{A -> ConditionalExpression[(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2))/\[Pi]^(3/2), a > 0]}}`

Addition. In 13.2 on Windows 10

```
Solve[(A \[Pi]^(3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)) == 1, A]
```

> `{{A -> (2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2))/\[Pi]^(3/2)}}`

The above answer is generic. Also `Solve` may do non-equivalent transformations of the original equation.

Comment: I added "Reals" after it, but to get the solution to "+", I had to use "[[2]]".

Comment: So how do you get a positive section, without using `[[2]]`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Wolfram Cloud (just a few minutes ago). I am on my cellphone which why I used Wolfram Cloud. In my computer I use 13.2.1.

```
{{A -> -a^(3/4)(2/π)^(3/4)}, {A -> a^(3/4)(2/π)^(3/4)}}
```

What version of Mathematica are you using?

By the way, your output is a solution. I suggest using *ToRadicals* to see the solution in the form you expected.

Comment: Are you sure? What is  the code used by you?

Comment: my wolfram version is 13.1

Comment: @我心永恒 Yes, I executed the Solve[A^2 ... version in Wolfram Cloud. That is the answer it returned. My computer is shut down for the night.

Comment: @IAmANaïf If I want to get `{A -> a^(3/4)(2/π)^(3/4)}`,but do not want to use `[[2]]`，what should I do?

Comment: @user64494 Quite sure. To get the first answer that 我心永恒 received the original Solve command had to have started Solve[A^2 ... and that is the version that returned the answer I gave.

Comment: @我心永恒 ToRadials[Solve[(A^2 \[Pi]^(3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)) == 1, A]]

Comment: @IAmANaïf will get `{{A -> I a^(3/4) (2/\[Pi])^(3/4)}, {A -> -a^(3/4) (2/\[Pi])^(3/4)}}`

Comment: i just redid Solve[(A^2 \[Pi]^(3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)) == 1, A], Wolfram Cloud returned {{A->-(a^(3and WolframAlpha returned A = (4 sqrt(2) a^(3/2))/π^(3/2) and sqrt(a)!=0. I copied the Wolfram Cloud answer by hand and erroneously. Mea Culpa. Changing Solve

Comment: I just redid Solve[(A^2 \[Pi]^(3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)) == 1, A], Wolfram Cloud returned {{A->-(a^(3/4)*(2/Pi)^(3/4))},{A->a^(3/4)*(2/Pi)^(3/4)}} and WolframAlpha returned A = (4 sqrt(2) a^(3/2))/π^(3/2) and sqrt(a)!=0. I copied the Wolfram Cloud answer by hand and erroneously. Mea Culpa. Changing Solve to Reduce in Wolfram Cloud returned (Sqrt[a]!=0&&A==-(a^(3/4)*(2/Pi)^(3/4)))||(Sqrt[a]!=0&&A==a^(3/4)*(2/Pi)^(3/4)). Solve in Wolfram Cloud failed to notice that $a$ was originally in the denominator and therefore must not be $0$ (division by $0$ error).

Comment: …Why do you post (almost) the same answer twice?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283019/1871

Comment: @xzczd  I regret that I had a cellphone crash in the midst of a comment entry. Last night's work was all on my cellphone. Do not be concerned overly. I was annoyed as well. I had two users both commenting at me at cross purposes. Lastly, there seemed to be problems communicating.